# Original Proof of Birkhoff's Ergodic Theorem

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Does anyone know where I can read Birkhoff's original proof of his pointwise ergodic theorem?

Answer (score 3):

You can read the original proof [here](http://www.pnas.org/content/17/12/656.full.pdf).